# Posted images at company wifi network by accident. I used my personal IPhone

Tags: wifi

Accidentally I sent my nude images through Grindr while  using the company wifi network. I sent these photos from my personal iPhone. Can they see these photos or only that I used the Grindr ? Should I worry ?

Comment: I used my iPhone. Not another device. That's not the same question

Comment: @Andy, Johnny's answer is nearly identical to the question I posted the duplicate of. Regardless of if you used an iphone or an android, the same principles apply.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Grindr uses HTTPS (I'm not about to go confirm), you don't have to register your device with IT and your employer didn't force you to install anything on your phone before they let you use it on the network, then at most all they'll see is that a device made a DNS request for Grindr, connected to their server and transmitted some data (but not *what* specifically).

Again, depending on intrusiveness, they may not even be able to tell *whose* device it is. If they just said "here's the wifi password" and sent you on your way, then I wouldn't worry at all.

In my experience you likely aren't the only person in the company with it installed, so I wouldn't worry about being outed by that either. We've removed it from more than a few corporate phones.

Comment: Thank you. My employer didn't enforce me to install anything on my iPhone. I don't care if they know I used Grindr. But I care if they see my nude photos

Comment: Could you check if Grinder uses Https? Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to visit Grindr without inviting scrutiny from my boss or my wife. The linked answer does mention it though: A quick web search reveals an evaluation of Grindr security: https://www.os3.nl/_media/reports/grindr.pdf in which you'll find that Grindr does in fact use SSL/TLS for its connection to the Grindr server, where all data is sent/received from (including pictures).